# Get selected rows in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` which looked as image below. When row is clicked, I want it to display all the selected row values.

[image]

**viewMovie**

```
public class viewMovie extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public viewMovie() throws Exception {
            initComponents();
            populateJTable();
        }

      // create a methode to populate data Into JTable from Mysql  database And Displaying Picture

        public void populateJTable() throws Exception{
            MyQuery mq = new MyQuery();
            ArrayList<Movie> list = mq.BindTable();
            String[] columnName = {"Title","Date","Time","Price","Hall","Description","Image"};
            Object[][] rows = new Object[list.size()][8];
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                //rows[i][0] = list.get(i).getID();
                rows[i][0] = list.get(i).getTitle();
                rows[i][1] = list.get(i).getDate();
                rows[i][2] = list.get(i).getTime();
                rows[i][3] = list.get(i).getPrice();
                rows[i][4] = list.get(i).getHall();
                rows[i][5] = list.get(i).getDescription();

                if(list.get(i).getImage() != null){

                 ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(list.get(i).getImage()).getImage()
                 .getScaledInstance(150, 120, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) );   

                rows[i][6] = image;
                }
                else{
                    rows[i][6] = null;
                }       
            }

            TheModel model = new TheModel(rows, columnName);
            jTable1.setModel(model);
            jTable1.setRowHeight(120);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(150);
        }




        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {
            ArrayList<Movie> list;
            jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
            jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            back= new javax.swing.JButton();

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                new Object [][] {
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null},
                    {null, null, null, null}
                },
                new String [] {
                    "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
                }
            ));

            jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() { // row is clicked
                public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                    int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
                    int selectedColumnIndex = jTable1.getSelectedColumn();
                    Object selectedObject = (Object) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
                    System.out.println(selectedObject);
                }

            });
            jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(228, 228, 228)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 291, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(261, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 272, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 194, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())         
            );



            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                                                            


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(viewMovie.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(viewMovie.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(viewMovie.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(viewMovie.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new viewMovie().setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
        private javax.swing.JButton back;


        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

When I click one cell, it suppose display all the row value, but it only display the cell value.

Comment: `Object selectedObject = (Object) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
                    System.out.println(selectedObject);` suggests to me that you're not printing the row at all

Comment: @BoDidely what is the correct way ?

Comment: You're selecting an object and printing it. You need to do that for each object in the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to print the data vector of the selected row:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
System.out.println(model.getDataVector().get(selectedRowIndex));
```

Or you can print the cell values of the row one after another:

```
TableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
for(int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++){
    if(i > 0){
        System.out.println(", ");
    }
    System.out.println(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex));
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: For the first one, I get error `TheModel cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer (JHead has given you example code), just a long comment.

> When row is clicked,

A proper GUI should be designed to work whether the user uses a mouse or the keyboard to select a row.

So you should be using a `ListSelectionListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more information and examples. The tutorial uses a JList but the concept is the same for a JTable as well.

Also, what if more than one row is selected?

> I want it to display all the selected row values.

What is the point of that? All the data is already displayed in the table.

Comment: When the row detect double click, i want it display another frame and pass all the row value to the  frame

Comment: @JohnJoe, Well then you should state that in your question. In any case you already have the answer from JHead. The example shows how to get the row Vector using the get getDataVector() method of the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: I use the JHead code but get `TheModel cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`

Comment: @JohnJoe, well we don't know what "TheModel" is. It looks like you are using a custom TableModel. I see no reason for doing this. So you can either add your own method to return the entire row of data or use the DefaultTableModel.